# building esp-open-sdk - crosstool-NG can't find expat-2.1.0

Tags: esp8266, crosstool-ng

I'm compiling the toolchain for ESP8266EX using [esp-open-sdk](https://github.com/pfalcon/esp-open-sdk)
and I get an error:

```
 Error happened in: do_expat_get[scripts/build/companion_libs/210-expat.sh@741]

 called from: do_companion_libs_get[scripts/build/companion_libs.sh@15]
called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@591]
```

I looked in crosstool-NG/build.log and it apparently can't find expat-2.1.0 in any type of tarball (zip,tar,tar.gz, etc)

```
Not at this location: "http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz"
Trying 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.xz'
```

I was able to download expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from another site (fedora) but I don't see how to tell the build project to find it on disk.

Comment: I was able to clone the crosstool-NG from github and copied it to the esp-open-sdk directory but I don't know how to tell the Makefile to skip over trying to clean and recompile it.

Comment: I copied the whole tarball: expat-2.1.0.tar.gz to crosstool-NG/.build/tarballs and started the build over and I think it's working.

Answer (score 1):

copy the tarball: expat-2.1.0.tar.gz to crosstool-NG/.build/tarballs and re-run the build and it should compile.

Comment: looks like they renamed the file:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/expat/files/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0-RENAMED-VULNERABLE-PLEASE-USE-2.3.0-INSTEAD.tar.gz/download

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes to this post in 2022: It seems like the build is failing because the servers where some dependencies were stored are down (I was getting isues with isl and expat. [This github issue](https://github.com/pfalcon/esp-open-sdk/issues/237) provides a solution:

```
cd crosstool-NG/.build/tarballs
wget https://libisl.sourceforge.io/isl-0.14.tar.gz
wget https://github.com/libexpat/libexpat/releases/download/R_2_1_0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
cd -
make
```

I would imagine this can be modified on the original script, haven't tried it myself yet.